# insert new value into phpmysql DB

Tags: php, file, upload

Having a moment with my code, i cannot seam to get the variable dbentry in to the database any ideas.

protected function moveFile($file)
    {

```
    $filename = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
    $success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $this->destination . $filename);
    if ($success) {
        $result = $file['name'] . ' was uploaded successfully';
        if (!is_null($this->newName)) {
            $result .= ', and was renamed ' . $this->newName;
            $dbentry = $this->newName;
                echo "$dbentry";

                        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "DBNAME", "PASSWORD", "USERNAME"); 
                        // Check connection
                        if($mysqli === false){
                            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
                        } 
                        // attempt insert query execution
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO files (file_name) VALUES ('$dbentry')";
                        if($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
                            echo "Records inserted successfully.";
                        } else{
                            echo "ERROR: Could not  execute " . $mysqli->error;
                        }
                        // Close connection
                        $mysqli->close();

                //
        }
        $result .= '.';
        $this->messages[] = $result;
    } else {
        $this->messages[] = 'Could not upload ' . $file['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please read about use of prepared statements with MySQLi.

Comment: what error is returned on failure?

Comment: only the echo'd responce of the new filename on screen, i check the DB and no entrys

Comment: I have now addressed the security issues you identified.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) one created the connection by:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

are you sure you have the arguments in right order?

Then the official way to check for the connection status is:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment unfortunately after doing that it still appears to not work, i have taken on board the issue of SQL injections and have now used declared variables to pass the values into the database connection.

Comment: I am talking about the order of the arguments - in your example code DBNAME is the second argument while it should be the last - have you checked that? What does the script say now? Does is pass the `die('Connect Error...` successfully?

Comment: Thanks Picard, the code now looks like the following,

Comment: Sorry fairly new to the stack system please see my entry below.